# ClassCastException when trying to get ORecordBytes with OrientDB via Graph API

Tags: java, orientdb

I tried to use OrientDB to store images/byte data and followed this tutorial: [Store it with ORecordBytes](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Binary-Data#store-it-with-orecordbytes) (I chose the "Store it with ORecordBytes" approach").

Storing the data with the following code doesn't seem to cause any trouble:

```
   Vertex vertex = db.addVertex("class:items");
   ...
   ORecordBytes imageRecord = new ORecordBytes(stream.toByteArray());
   imageRecord.save();
   vertex.setProperty("image", imageRecord);
   ...
   db.commit();
```

However, when I attempt to retrieve the data like this:

```
    ORecordBytes imageRecord = vertex.getProperty("image");
```

... I get this for the line above:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ORecordBytes cannot be cast to com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.getElement(OrientBaseGraph.java:1145)
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientElement.getProperty(OrientElement.java:186)
at service.database.DAO.OrientDBGraphAPIItemDAO.vertexToItem(OrientDBGraphAPIItemDAO.java:154)
at service.database.DAO.OrientDBGraphAPIItemDAO.create(OrientDBGraphAPIItemDAO.java:68)
at testing.TestApplication.main(TestApplication.java:69)
```

I don't really see at which point I am making a cast to ODocument but I don't know the internals of OrientDB. As the tutorial is written for the Document API I am wondering if that could be the cause? Or am I just missing something else?

Comment: Got a similar error with version 2 rc1, updated to version 2 rc2 and the issue got fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the Luigi's suggestions, but this has already been fixed in release 1.7.8:

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/2643

Answer (score 2):

the cast is not being made in your code, but in OrientBaseGraph class, that is an OrientDB internal class.

You should solve this problem with the following syntax:

```
vertex.getRecord().field("image");
```

Anyway, I think it can be considered an issue, so I suggest you to report it in OrientDB issue tracker.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, seems to work. Of course this way one has to  cast the vertex which is only asserted to be a `com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Vertex` to a `com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientVertex`. Very dirty, but as a temporary workaround (until 1.7.8) this is a good idea :).